# Can delayed animation attributes override existing ones?

Tags: css, sass

### Situation

- The DOM element initial state is `opacity: 0`.
- I'm adding animation class to a DOM element. Aside of the animation, this class has an initial state of `opacity: 1`.

> ```
> .animation { 
>     opacity: 1;
>     animation(fadeIn 1s 200ms ease-in-out); 
> }
> ```

- The animation is executed with a delay of 200ms, and has an initial state of `opacity: 0`.

> ```
> @keyframes fadeIn {
>   0% {
>     opacity: 0;
>   }
>
>   100% {
>     opacity: 1;
>   }
> }
> ```

### Problem

When the animation class gets apended to the DOM element, the element becomes instantly visible for 200ms, after which, the fadeIn animation begins by flickering the DOM element back to invisible state. Contrary to this, I would like for the animation (keyframes) attribute `opacity:0` to overwrite the animation class attribute `opacity:1` and as a result have a smooth fadeIn animation.

Reason for this approach is older-browser support.

EDIT: Added the actual project code ( for clarification purposes )

> ```
> @for $i from 1 through 3 {
>   &.showAddonColumn#{$i} {
>
>       td:nth-child( #{$i + 1} ) {
>           display: table-cell;
>       }
>
>       @for $j from 1 through 15 {
>           tr:nth-child( #{$j} ) {
>
>               td {
>
>                   .checkable {
>                       @include transform-origin(50%, 0%);
>                       @include animation(leafShow 1s #{$j*100ms} cubic-bezier(.37,0,.16,.94) 1);
>                       @include animation-fill-mode(forwards);
>                   }
>               }
>           }
>       }
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: `Reason for this approach is older-browser support.` You can never fix an old browser. Why not work around the whole problem instead and only apply the animations to modern browsers? Modernizr can detect it with cssanimations. http://modernizr.com/docs/#features-css

Comment: @luqmaan I totally agree on modernizr. It's just that I'm always hunting for the most elegant approach.

Answer (score 2):

You could manually delay the animation itself:

```
@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    17% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

and extend the animation:

```
animation: fadeIn 1200ms ease-in-out;
```

Comment: I edited the question so we can further clarify the problem. You'll see there why this approach won't cut it.